# Change Cell Format in Datatables.net Exported Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, datatables

I have a server sided Datatable on my UI. While exporting data in that datatable as an excel I noticed some number type values lacks leading zeros. For example: 0012345 resides in cell as 12345.

I have tried to use customize method that Datatables api supports.

```
customize: function (xlsx) {
                    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                    $('row c', sheet).attr('s', '0');
                }
```

This should make all cell's data format 'Text' as says in here [https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5#Built-in-styles](https://stackoverflow.com).
But it did not work.
Some cells have <t></t> tag in their values but some have <v></v>. I suppose it did not work because of that but I don't know why.

Comment: it should work fine. check input data you pass to the datatable, how does it look like, does it maybe lose leading zeros in the process, maybe gets converted to number..